# Combine a set of shell scripts with internal dependencies into one?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I'm developing a set of shell scripts and for ease of development, the functions are often split across various files.

So the final binary scripts which I expect the end user to use require them to have all the relevant "library" scripts installed in the right location.

I am trying to find a way that allows me to develop the scripts with the same logical split in files, but then I can *merge* them all into a single binary script.

In the naive case, it would recursively go through all the sourced files and include them in the same file (similar to the pre-processing step in C compilers). The more involved version would also identify which functions are unused and trim them out.

Does anything like this exist? If not, I might consider writing it, but would be happy to hear about potential pitfalls that I should account for

Comment: have a look at [shc](https://github.com/neurobin/shc)

Comment: I looked at shc, but it tends to create C source code which would need to be compiled into a binary. I was hoping to still have a shell script at the end of the whole process

Comment: Nope. You can freeze a Python script into a single executable. I'm looking to do the same for Bash. Not use Docker

Comment: If you have some python functionality in mind that you're hoping to duplicate for a shell script then maybe you should add a python tag to this so someone familiar with whatever that python functionality is can chime in.

Comment: When you source the library scripts with relative paths like `source "${calculated_topdir}/shlib/util.sh"`, you can take the complete set yogether and deploy in another location.

Comment: When one "freeze[s] a Python script into a single executable", one of the operative words is *executable* -- you get a native ELF binary out the other end (even if it's just bundling together the Python interpreter and the individual scripts). It sounds like you explicitly don't want that, which is why I've reworded the title.

Comment: @EdMorton, boo hiss re: suggesting the Python tag -- folks knowing Python may well know what the OP wants, but that doesn't mean they have any idea how to accomplish it with shell. Especially not how to do it *well* (such that error messages keep the original filenames and line numbers, or such). Better to reword the question to explain the goal without needing to reference Python.

Comment: @darnir, ...the level of dynamicism in POSIX shell's execution model makes a recompiler (a la the Closure Compiler for JavaScript or its various competitors) practically impossible. One can do textual substitution easily enough, but dead-code detection is effectively impossible -- one simply can't predict the ways in which the runtime environment (exported functions, variables with surprising values inherited from the environment, etc) will change the codepaths in use.

Comment: Similarly, a shell script can dynamically list which functions are defined and operate on that list; I frequently use that in practice, looking for functions that start with a given prefix and exposing them as subcommands. Code analysis tools that Identify that kind of pattern and determine whether a function can be accessed by code that's inspecting its runtime environment and/or generating names of functions to run using dynamic strings (f/e, user-requested subcommand names) is not feasible.

Comment: @darnir, ...that said, if you want to see what state-of-the-art is in POSIX shell (and bash) runtime code analysis, I'd suggest taking a look at the codebase to [shellcheck](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck).

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this before, in Arch Linux' [devtools](https://git.archlinux.org/devtools.git/tree/?id=4c08847bfa7776abb884fef289a25c1cef9883fb) repo. They use [m4](https://www.gnu.org/software/m4/) to process `.in` files.

It's just templating though. And you might not need anything more.